# Number of derangements $f(1)=2 , f(2)=3$

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of derangements of the set $\{1,2,…,n\}$ such that $f(1)=2, f(2)=3$.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for derangement a of. $n-2$ objects where one of them. $(3)$ cannot be matched. If $f(3)=1$, you need a derangement of $n-3$ items. Otherwise, you need a derangement of $n-3$ where one cannot be matched. That should suggest a recurrence.

Comment: I meant derangements (I wrote "permutation", my mistake)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The answer to this question is calculated in a very
similar way to the one done to prove that the number of permutations
on a set of size $n$ is $n!$

I suggest going over this calculation and making adjustments that
correspond to the constraints in the question

Comment: I meant derangements (I wrote "permutation", my mistake)

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

Since $f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=3$, we can consider bijections f from the set $A=\{3,4,\cdots,n\}$ to the set $B=\{1,4,5,\cdots,n\}$ which move every element.

Since $f(3)\not=3$, let $A_i$ be the set of mappings which leave i fixed for $4\le i\le n$, and then

find $\lvert A_4^{c}\cap\cdots\cap A_n^{c}\rvert$ using Inclusion-Exclusion.